# Hovering just one cell of a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

How can I hover just one cell of a table? I don't want to hover all of the row. Here is my table HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="danger" colspan="4">Comprobante de Pago</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="warning" width="10%">Fecha:</td>
            <td colspan="2" id="vertical_align">sdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" class="asd">Client</td>
            <td colspan="1">NAME</td>
            <td colspan="1">NAME 2</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">asd</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr class="info">
            <td colspan="3">asd</td>
        </tr>
```

Note: I'm using Bootstrap for the hover.
(I don't mind if the problem can be fixed without using Bootstrap.)

Comment: Have you tried adding a class to the `<td class="myclass">` then using `.myclass:hover` in the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite bootsrap rules with a selector [strong enough : see specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Seems to be `tr:hover` to reset here first :

```
.table.table-hover.table-bordered tr:hover {/* selector strong enough to overwrite bootsrap rule */
  background:none;/* remove bg */
}
```

Then apply the rule you need to your tds, using any attributes used here (class, id, colspan, rowspan, ...)

```css
.table.table-hover.table-bordered tr:hover {
  background: none;
}
td:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}
/* a few selector examples */
td[colspan]:hover {
  background: lime;
}
td[colspan] + td[colspan]:hover {
  background:turquoise;
}
td[colspan="2"]:hover {
  background: gold;
}
td[rowspan]:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="danger" colspan="3">Comprobante de Pago</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="warning" width="10%">Fecha:</td>
    <td colspan="2" id="vertical_align">sdf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" class="asd">Client</td>
    <td colspan="1">NAME</td>
    <td colspan="1">NAME 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">asd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info">
    <td colspan="2">asd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Notice: i updated the table code about `rowspan` and `colspan` values (`colspan="1"` doesn't even nedd to be set, it is defaut value)

Comment: Thanks a lot, also i would like to know how to set different width sizes to the cell "Fecha:" and to the cell "Client", as you notice I`ve set 10 % of width for the cell "Fecha", but if i woul like to set 30 % to the cell "Client", it doesn't allow me.

Comment: oh, so it isn't possible to have 2 cells with different widths?

Comment: @JoanPerezLozano  **you need to trick it** like it is built on a few more columns to be able to break it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGMqWZ **Actually `.asd` and `.warning` belong to the same column, they will be same width anyhow`** :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
table td:hover{
    background-color: magenta;
}
```

then remove the class `table-hover` here `<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">`

Answer (score 0):

Apply the formatting to the TD element.

```
.table td:hover{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that should do the trick...

```css
table tr td:hover{
  background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="danger" colspan="4">Comprobante de Pago</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="warning" width="10%">Fecha:</td>
                <td colspan="2" id="vertical_align">sdf</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" class="asd">Client</td>
                <td colspan="1">NAME</td>
                <td colspan="1">NAME 2</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">asd</td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="info">
                <td colspan="3">asd</td>
            </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use important.

```
.table td:hover{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this apply to All table cells? OP asks how to hover "just one"

Comment: I think you can use a class or an id:

Comment: `.table .asd:hover{
    background-color: red !important;
}`